# reshape a data frame pandas

Tags: pandas, reshape

I have:

```
data1=['id1','id2','id3','id1','id5']
data2=['','A','','B','']
data3=['m1','m1','m1','m2','m2']
data4=['1.22','sd','EUR','1.456','GB1234']
pd.DataFrame({'identifier':data1,'name':data2,'grp':data3,'value':data4})

    identifier  name    grp value
0   id1                 m1  1.22
1   id2         A       m1  sd
2   id3                 m1  EUR
3   id1         B       m2  1.456
4   id5                 m2  GB1234
```

I want:

```
    id1     id2 id3 id5
A   1.220   sd  EUR 
B   1.456           GB1234
```

Any suggestions?
My real data has 109 identifiers, 6k names, 1k groups
Some notes:

- There is the potential for all identifiers to be same bt different groups
- In the end, I would like to have all of the identifiers as a column, the name as the index, and the values as the value

I tried `df2=df.pivot(values='value',columns='field',index='ticker')`
and got the error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshap`

I tried [reshaping a data frame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615158/reshaping-a-data-frame-in-pandas) but it is a little different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate `first` and if need replace groups by first non empty string `name` add `rename`:

```
s = df.assign(name = df['name'].replace('', np.nan)).groupby('grp')['name'].first()

df2=df.pivot_table(values='value',
                   columns='identifier',
                   index='grp', 
                   aggfunc='first').rename(s)
print (df2)
identifier    id1  id2  id3     id5
grp                                
A            1.22   sd  EUR     NaN
B           1.456  NaN  NaN  GB1234
```